# ASP.NET MVC EntityFramework: how to use LINQ inside ActionResult controller method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveCollaborationEntry(int collaborationEntryID = 0)
    {
        using (var collaborationEntriesContext = new CollaborationEntryContext())
        {
            collaborationEntriesContext.Collaborations.Remove(
                collaborationEntriesContext.Collaborations.ElementAtOrDefault(collaborationEntryID));

            collaborationEntriesContext.SaveChanges();               
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

When this method gets invoked, the exception is torwn:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'annaBevzenkoPortfolioMVC.AboutMe.CollaborationEntry
>   ElementAtOrDefault[CollaborationEntry](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[annaBevzenkoPortfolioMVC.AboutMe.CollaborationEntry],
>   Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

I am pretty new to Entity.. can someone help me?

Comment: Make sure you bring in the `System.Linq` namespace so it can find the extension method `ElementAtOrDefault`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've checked that. No problems with that...

Comment: Try to use .Where instead of ElementAtOrDefault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framewok does not know how to translate into SQL Query the follwoing method `ElementAtOrDefault`.

You need to use `Find` method by doing the code below:

```
collaborationEntriesContext.Collaborations.Find(collaborationEntryID)
```

Comment: Really? Consider this link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/crud-operation-in-connected-scenario-entity-framework.aspx. There is the example using ElementAt(int).

Comment: But this instruction `studentList.ElementAt<Student>(0)` is applied on a Linq TO Objects studentList not on a DbSet<Student> :)

Comment: `var studentList = context.Students.ToList<Student>();` sudentList here is a collection of Object not and DbSet<Student>() because of ToList()

Comment: Mark it as an answer if this answer satisfied you, please :)

Comment: I am waiting for 2 minutes more to do that.